# UE4 Сломался редактор blueprint

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если создать blueprint, открыть его все хорошо, но если закрыть и заново открыть пропадают все вкладки. В меню window нету viewport и много чего еще. Раньше этой проблемы не было, возможно это из-за того что я наследуюсь от С++ класса, но я пробовал создать bp от Actor тоже самое(

вот скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот реализация С++ класса, от которого наследуюсь:
MyActor.h:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h" 
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class PROJECT_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "My")
        USceneComponent* scene;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "My")
        UStaticMeshComponent* mainObject;
```

};

MyActor.cpp:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MyActor.h"

// Sets default values
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    scene = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("Scene"));
    mainObject = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("main object"));

    RootComponent = scene;
    mainObject->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    mainObject->AddRelativeLocation(FVector(0, 0, 3), false);

}
```

Щас 100% найдутся люди которые проголосуют против вопроса без причины! Если голосуете, то пишите в комментах что вас не устраевает в вопросе!

P.S. Я гуглил, c такой проблемой кто-то сталкивался, но сайт не доступен(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1: Перезапуск движка проблему не решил((

Жду вашей помощи! Заранее спасибо!)

upd: по корректнее будет сказать, что редактор blueprint сломался после повторного запуска

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вроде нашел решение. Если открыть Class Defaults в классе там будет такая подпись: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если тыкнуть на "Open Full Blueprind Editor", то все открывается

Comment: Все было так просто???? Где ты раньше был, брат???

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема не в вашем классе, а в движке, подозреваю это просто баг движка, попробуйте сделать следующее:

1. Закройте движок и удалите папки Intermediate и Saved они находятся в папки с проектом
2. Запустите проект и если проблема не решилась пересоздайте класс и повторите предыдущий пункт.

Comment: Извините, пересоздать класс в каком смысле? А если этот класс очень очень большой? Я его попробовал скопировать, сохранил, закрыл движок, удалил папки, открыл проект, так же фигня. Но если я пересоздам класс, и потом закрою редактор blueprint то опять так же будет.