# UE5 Сломался редактор Blueprint class

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-5, blueprint

У меня возникла проблема при создании и редактировании Blueprint в Unreal Engine. После перезахода в него снова, появляется пустое окно, в котором ничего нельзя сделать. Я уже переустанавливал движок, сбрасывал его до предыдущей версии и создавал новый проект, но это не решило проблему. Я нашел пост по поводу этой ситуации, но там не было решения моей ситуации. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Видео с проблемой: https://youtu.be/VZwLWnKn-X4
Ссылка на пост: [UE4 Сломался редактор blueprint](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085242/ue4-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-blueprint)